# Need help with Django tutorial

Tags: python, django

I'm doing the Django tutorial here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/intro/tutorial03/

My TEMPLATE_DIRS in the settings.py looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

    "/webapp2/templates/"
    "/webapp2/templates/polls"
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".

    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.

    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.

)
```

My urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^polls/$', 'polls.views.index'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/results/$', 'polls.views.results'),
    (r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
from django.template import Context, loader
from polls.models import Poll
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    t = loader.get_template('c:/webapp2/templates/polls/index.html')
    c = Context({
        'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I think I am getting the path of my template wrong because when I simplify the views.py code to something like this, I am able to load the page.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")
```

My index template file is located at C:/webapp2/templates/polls/index.html. What am I doing wrong?

```
This is the error I am getting:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 674, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 141, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 180, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 76, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/webapp2/templates/"
    "/webapp2/templates/polls"
)
```

Python concatenates those strings during compilation if you don't put a comma in between.

And another thing: Usually you don't need to hardcode template directories. The following should be enough for most cases:

```
def fromRelativePath(*relativeComponents):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *relativeComponents).replace("\\","/")

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    fromRelativePath("templates"),
)
```

This will make Django search in "yoursite/templates" and in the "templates" directory of each intalled app.

Comment: I tried adding that function and changing the TEMPLATE_DIRS but it still didn't work. So, do I need to put a comma in between `"/webapp2/templates/"` and `"/webapp2/templates/polls"`. The comments said to leave it as a string. In anycase, I tried with commas and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Nai: Of course you need the commas. And since you're on Windows, the path should rather begin with "C:/" (though that doesn't make a difference for Python). Now that you've edited your question, it's obvious that you're missing a "500.html" template. You can either use `DEBUG=True` (which uses the default traceback template if an error occurs) or create such a file in your templates directory. I guess that the real problem is something different - use the development server and `DEBUG=True` setting to find the error.

Comment: Ok it was a typo but turning on DEBUG has helped me to fix the bugs. Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have added 'webapp2' to your INSTALLED_APPS

Answer (score 2):

Try to load templates from related path, not from absolute. In your case try this:

```
 t = loader.get_template('index.html')
```

Comment: This probably means you have an Internal server error, status 500. Try to enclose your code in try-except statement and see if it works fine.

Comment: The thing is when I swap out the views.py code to something simpler, the page works! e.g `def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")`

Comment: Which line exactly? Try creating some simple template, without any context and define another view: def another(request): t = loader.get_template('new_template.html') return HttpResponse(t.render(Context({}))) And tell me what happens with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `C:` in front of each path in TEMPLATE_DIRS?

Comment: get_template is normally used with only the template filename, or a relative path, but I see you're using the full path. What about changing that?